# Join multiple tables in a ternary

Tags: sql

I have a 3 tables (customers, customerID is PK)(services, serviceID is PK)(equipment, equID is PK). The second two tables have a cost associated with them. All 3 tables connect individually to a table (Billing, transID is the PK). Another process puts transactions in for each customer which charges them for their services individually. I would like to generate a query that pulls all transactions and costs for related equipment and services. When I tried to join cus->billing->service->billing->equip it causes some weirdness. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

```
Select * from Customer as c 
inner join Billing as b on c.customerID=b.customerID
inner join Service as s on b.ServID=s.ServID
inner join Billing on s.ServID=b.ServID
inner join Equipment as e on b.EquID=e.EquID AND b.Serial=e.Serial
where c.customerID=1
```

Comment: Can you show the query that you tried?

Comment: @ChrisCarr I just updated it with the code I am trying now. It is a reading as successful but not showing any results even though I know customer 1 has transactions.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: You can get rid of the join where you are using Billing for the second time. Using each table once should suffice.

Comment: you are joining the same table (Billing) twice without an `as` name (how does that even work). Give them a name like b1, b2, etc. and don't forget to change the refs in `on`s.

Comment: Thanks everyone I got it working with this code
    Select * from Customer as c 
    inner join Billing as b on c.customerID=b.customerID
    full outer join Service as s on b.ServID=s.ServID
    full outer join Equipment as e on b.EquID=e.EquID AND b.Serial=e.Serial
    where c.customerID=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with some help from friends and the comments. Final code is below.

```
Select * from Customer as c 
inner join Billing as b on c.customerID=b.customerID
left join Service as s on b.ServID=s.ServID
left join Equipment as e on b.EquID=e.EquID AND b.Serial=e.Serial
where c.customerID=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although  you have joined  Billing  table twice  , you haven't  used the second one. I think you can remove  following  from  the  query.

```
inner join Billing on s.ServID=b.ServID --(4th line  of  the  query)
```